# React state passes from one component to the next inconsistently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two components: LeagueSelect and TeamSelect.

All I'm trying to do right now is pass the checkedLeagues state from LeagueSelect to TeamSelect.

It's currently setup to have the checkboxes in TeamSelect be checked if the corresponding league is checked.

**The issue:** the state passes from LeagueSelect to TeamSelect inconsistently.

This is a video of what it looks like:
https://streamable.com/2i06g

When a box is unchecked, the state updates 'in team', as you can see in the console.log, but, when you try to check the same box again the state does not update in team.

I initially tried to implement this with redux, thought this issue was a redux issue, moved to directly passing state to the child component, and realized that the issue must be somewhere else.

This is my LeagueSelect component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Modal, TouchableHighlight, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native'
import { loadLeagues } from '../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Check from './CheckBox'
import axios from "axios"
import { loadCards, loadTeams, changeLeagues } from '../actions'
import { Icon } from 'native-base'
import TeamSelect from './TeamSelect'


class LeagueSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: false,
            checked: [],
            checkedLeagues: [],
            checkMessage: ''
        }
    }

    setModalVisible(visible) {
        this.setState({modalVisible: visible})
        if(this.state.checked.length === 0) {
            this.props.league.map(
                (v, i) => {
                    this.state.checked.push(true)
                    this.state.checkedLeagues.push(v.acronym)
                }
            )
        }
        this.setState({ checkMessage: '' })
    }

    changeCheck = (index, acronym) => {
        //local variable to create query param
        firstString = []
        //adds to local variable if not checked, takes out variable if checked
        if(!this.state.checkedLeagues.includes(acronym)) {
            firstString.push(acronym)
        } else {
            firstString.filter(v => { return v !== acronym})
        }
        //adds leagues that could be in the current state that were not just passed in
        this.state.checkedLeagues.map(
            (v, i) => {
                if(v !== acronym) {
                    firstString.push(v)
                }
            }
        )

        //updates checked leagues state
        //makes api call with parameters set
        //prevents all leagues being unselected
        if(acronym === this.state.checkedLeagues[0] && firstString.length === 0) {
            this.setState({ checkMessage: `Don't you want something to look at?` })
        } else {
            if(!this.state.checkedLeagues.includes(acronym)){
                this.state.checkedLeagues[this.state.checkedLeagues.length] = acronym
                this.setState({ checkedLeagues: this.state.checkedLeagues })
            } else {
                newChecked  = this.state.checkedLeagues.filter(v => { return v !== acronym})
                this.setState({checkedLeagues: newChecked})
            }


            //updating the check
            this.state.checked[index] = !this.state.checked[index]
            this.setState({ checked: this.state.checked })

            queryString = []

            firstString.map(
                (v, i) => {
                    if (queryString.length < 1) {
                        queryString.push(`?league=${v}`)
                    } else if (queryString.length >= 1 ) {
                        queryString.push(`&league=${v}`)
                    }
                }
            )

            axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/reports${queryString.join('')}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.props.loadCards(response.data)
                    })
        }       
    }

    render() {


      return (

        <View style={{ position: 'relative'}}>
                        <Text
                            style={{
                                paddingTop: 8,
                                paddingLeft: 5,
                                fontSize: 15
                            }}
                        >Leagues</Text>
                        <View
                            style={{
                                flexDirection:"row",
                            }}
                        >
                            {this.props.league === null ?'' : this.props.league.map(
                                (v, i) => {
                                    return(
                                            <View 
                                                key={i}
                                                style={{
                                                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                                                    flexDirection:"row",
                                                    top: 4,

                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <Check
                                                    checked={this.state.checked[i]}
                                                    index={i}
                                                    value={v.acronym}
                                                    changeCheck={this.changeCheck}
                                                />
                                                <Text
                                                    style={{
                                                        paddingLeft: 23,

                                                    }}
                                                >{v.acronym}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                    )
                                }
                            )}
                        </View>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            paddingLeft: 10,
                            paddingTop: 12,
                            fontStyle: 'italic',
                            color: '#F4AF0D'
                        }}
                    >{this.state.checkMessage}</Text>
                    <TeamSelect  checkedLeagues={this.state.checkedLeagues}/>
                </View>
            </View>
      );
    }
  }

export default LeagueSelect
```

This is my TeamSelect component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { loadTeams, loadLeagues } from '../actions'
import Check from './CheckBox'

class TeamSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            checked: [],
            checkedTeams: [],
            setOnce: 0
        }
    }


    render() {
    console.log('in team', this.props.checkedLeagues)

        return(
          <View>
              { 
                  this.props.team === null ?'' : this.props.team.map(
                      (v, i) => {
                         return(
                                <View key={i}>
                                    <Check
                                        checked={ this.props.checkedLeagues.includes(v.league.acronym) ? true : false }
                                        index={i}
                                        value={v.team_name}
                                        changeCheck={this.changeCheck}
                                    />

                                { v.team_name === undefined ? null :
                                    <Text>{v.team_name}</Text>}
                                </View>
                            )
                      }
                  )
             }
          </View>
        )
    }
}


export default TeamSelect
```

Comment: too much to go through, only post the relevant parts

Comment: You have posted the same component twice

Comment: @AvinKavish just update, sorry

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging.

Comment: I think the issue is in the `changeCheck` method, the state should be immutable and only be changed by using the `setState` method

Comment: @WilomGfx I just revised

Comment: @AvinKavish THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.setState({ checkedLeagues: this.state.checkedLeagues })`

Statements like these can cause issues as you are mutating and setting the state to the same object. The reference to checked leagues doesn't get updated and react may not trigger a render. Use this instead

`this.setState({ checkedLeagues: [...this.state.checkedLeagues] })`

But this whole approach to the problem is wrong, you should use one leagues object that has a checked property to it, and pass it down.

make you league object look like this,

```
const leagues = [
  {
  acronym: 'abc',
  checked: false,
  teams: [ ...array of teams here ]
  },
  ...
]
```

When you pass it down to `TeamSelect`, you can map it like this

```
const { leagues } = this.props
{leagues && leagues.map((league, i) => league.teams.map((team, j) (
<View key={team.team_name}>
 <Check
  checked={league.checked}
  index={i + i * j}
  value={team.team_name}
  changeCheck={() => this.changeCheck(i, j)}
 />
 {team.team_name && <Text>{team.team_name}</Text>}
</View>)))}
```

Same with leagueSelect, you can map leagues like this:

```
const { leagues } = this.state
{leagues.map((league, i) => (  
  <View 
    key={league.acronym}
    style={{
      alignSelf: 'flex-end',
      flexDirection:"row",
      top: 4,
    }}>
      <Check
        checked={league.checked}
        index={i}
        value={league.acronym}
        changeCheck={this.changeCheck}
      />
      <Text
       style={{
       paddingLeft: 23,
       }}
       >{league.acronym}</Text>
    </View>
  )
)}
```

Note: leagues have to be copied from props to state for you to mutate it. I just typed this so it will need some changes before it runs, it's just meant to show you the "react way" of coding this.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html